# Random errors when using PIL on windows

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have made a graphical sorting algorithm using pygame and PIL, and it works fine on Ubuntu (Linux), but whenever I run it on Windows (I've run it on both windows 7 and windows 10) it can only get a bit of the way through the program before I get a random error. The weird part about it is, it happens during a loop, and the loop will always run multiple times before an error occurs.

The error happens while saving. Here are some examples:

Random error #1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dylan\Desktop\sorting (graphical).py", line 13, in <module>
    square = Image.open(square_location)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2280, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'square.jpg'
```

Random error #2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dylan\Desktop\sorting (graphical).py", line 52, in <module>
    square.save(square_location)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1682, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "wb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'square.jpg'
```

And random error #3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dylan\Desktop\sorting (graphical).py", line 103, in <module>
    square.save(square_location)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1682, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'square.jpg'
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

And in case you wanted to know:

Python 3.4.3

pygame 1.9.2b1

pillow 3.3.1

**EDIT:**

I have recreated what is happening with the following code.

```
import pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.display import flip
from PIL import Image

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((998, 549))

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    data = list()
    for i in range(83): data.append(random.randint(1, 183))

    for value in range(83):
        square = Image.open('square.jpg')
        square = square.resize((10, 3 * data[value]))
        square.save('square.jpg')
        square = pygame.image.load('square.jpg')
        screen.blit(square, (12 * value + 2, 549 - 3 * data[value]))
    flip()
```

Now, if you run this code to see for yourself, run it a few times so that you see the errors are all random. Also, it may take a few seconds for the error to show.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you post the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: You lose `python path definitions`.  Working directory never a system directory. Give full path or `path = os.getcwd()+ "\\"+ filename`

Comment: dsgdfg, I tried the full directory, with no change in the outcome. Thanks for the idea, though.